# Removing reputation, when answer become irrelevant over the time due to change of technology

Tags: discussion

It is a desired behaviour to remove reputation, when answer become irrelevant, and user marks another one as a right one, as the technology it relies to changes?

For example, react 16 is out, so many things is deprecated or works differently, like [rendering multiple items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32577886/is-there-a-way-to-render-multiple-react-components-in-the-react-render-functio/35292609#35292609).

But two years ago, answer that is not possible and it must be wrapped WAS correct. So when the library changes, why am I penalised? Should it really be removing points in these cases?

**Clarification**: I am not 'crying' about losing the right answer tag or the reputation, merely curios if this realy is the keen behaviour.

Comment: A new version coming out does not necessarily mean people stop using older versions. Also, how are you penalised? If your answer refers to a specific version of the library, just updated it to say so. And if you also include the current solution, even better.

Comment: To clarify: You are essentially asking why you lose the +15 rep if the OP decides to unaccept your answer, right?

Comment: Keiwan: No, I am asking why the points are removed, when answer is unaccepted over a long period of time due to tech change, not that the answer is not good or a better solution is found. Because, as yannis mentioned, for older versions the answer still is valid.

Comment: The OP can accept and unaccept at their leisure. Nothing to see here.

Comment: But the OP accepting or unaccepting an answer doesn't mean that the answer is right or wrong anyway. It just means that the answer is currently the most helpful to the OP.

Comment: If your answer is any good, it will have gained upvotes in the process. The 15 points for the accepted answer are just a "bonus." I think you're right and a moral case could be made that they should not be removed if the accepted answer changes, but it's really a minuscule issue and I expect the official reaction will be something like this: https://imgur.com/IS9nqlN

Comment: gnat: no, that is about having historical first best answer tag.

Comment: Discovering that SO users expect you to maintain a post for the rest of your natural life can be a bit of a letdown, yes.  But you'll have to keep in mind that what is unusual is that you never lost any rep on your contributions before.  It is entirely normal, you'll get used to it.  Or you mutter "this sucks" and never come back again, that happens.

Answer (score 10):

The accept vote doesn't convey *this is the right answer*, it only conveys *this answer helped the OP*. There have been plenty of cases where even wrong answers were marked *helpful*.

It still is and will for the foreseeable future the sole responsibility of the OP to decide which answer helps them. And, yes that can change over time, for all kind of reasons.

Your arguments about how valid your answer is or was or how unjust the decision of the OP was are all in vain. There is nothing you can do about it, even bringing this to meta will not help. At best you can update an existing answer when newer or different approaches emerge and then still you're not free from unaccept votes, just as much you're free from accept votes years after posting. Or do you suggest we limit that as well?

The effects this has on *your* reputation shouldn't be a factor at all. It is all about the content and the quality of it for future visitors. caring too much about rep brings in the wrong motivation. Just for the record: That answer gave you 6 upvotes, total rep earned: 60. I wouldn't complain. Good answers tend to attract much more upvotes then accept votes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just to clarify, i did not asked here because I pity my lost reputation, just wanted to know how it works and why it works this way. I've sent a message via contact section, where they did not provide me any closer insight, only that questions like this should be asked on meta. So I asked to better understand the mechanism (in help section it is not too detailed)

Comment: @PavelHasala fair enough, I've slightly edit my answer to not make it sound to negative towards you.